# Is it correct to use "serve" in this context?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

> A long queue of citizens were waiting at the reception of the ministry to be **served**.

They intended to submit official documents or something, and I am not sure whether "served" works here.

Comment: It's fine. The government clerk receiving those documents is performing a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "served" is fine, if you consider that the ministry is providing a service. There are other words that you could use, from the mechanical "to be processed" to the literal "to submit their documents".

I'd move "to be served" closer to "waiting", so the long phrase "at the reception of the ministry" can go at the end

> ...waiting to be served at the reception of the ministry.